# Explain how exponential expression simplifies?

Tags: math, expression

It's been a very long time and I cannot find a simple answer or rule to this...  Anyone mind explaining how this is equal?

(i.e. what are the steps needed to get the side to the left of the "=" sign to equal the side on the right?)

(36^24  -  35^24)  /  36^24    =    1 - (35/36)^24

Comment: You should try posting questions like this on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: C'mon man, this doesn't belong on math.stackexchange.com.  It's nothing more than the simplest algebra problem that ever was.  A grammar school student should be able to do this.

Comment: @duffymo - At the same time, it does not belong here either.

Comment: @woodchips - agreed.  That's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:

```
(36^24 - 35^24) / 36^24
```

Apply the distributive property -- that is, `(a*b)*c = a*c + b*c`:

```
= 36^24 / 36^24 - 35^24 / 36^24
```

Simplify the first expression, because `a/a = 1` provided `a != 0`:

```
= 1 - 35^24 / 36^24
```

Now we can apply `a^n * b^n = (a * b)^n`, for `a = 35`, `b = 1/36`, and `n = 24`:

```
= 1 - (35/36)^24
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you divide both terms by 36^24:

```
(36^24 - 35^24) / 36^24 = 36^24/36^24 - 35^24/36^24
```

`36^24/36^24` is, of course, just 1.  Recall also that `a^x/b^x = (a/b)^x`, and then you can make the last substitution:

```
1 - 35^24/36^24 = 1 - (35/36)^24
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider a simpler expression first.

**(a-b)/c**

This can be expressed as

**a/c - b/c**

Now lets consider how exponents work.

a^3 = a * a * a.

b^3 = b * b * b.

So, a^3/b^3 = (a*a*a)/(b*b*b)

```
          = (a/b) * (a/b) * (a/b)

          = (a/b)^3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply we have

```
 (a - b)/a  = (a/a) - (b/a) = 1 - (b/a)
```

from your equation we substitute

```
 a = 36^24,   b = 35^24
```

which gives

```
 (a - b)/a = 1 - (b/a) 

 = 1 - (35^24 / 36^24) 

 = 1 - (35/36)^24
```

If any of the above does not make sense, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation and then review the answers here again.